The Grassmannian $G(k,n) \subset G(k,n+1)$ as the zero locus of the tautological sub-bundle
Following my question
Pushforward of structure sheaf with respect to canonical inclusion of Grassmannian
I have a follow up question I would like to ask. I would have put this as a comment, but I feel this is an interesting question in its own right.
It is well-known that the grassmannain $Gr(k,n) \subset Gr(k,n+1)$ can be seen as the zero locus of a regular global section of the dual tautological bundle $\mathcal{U}^{\vee}$ on $Gr(k,n+1)$. I am trying to prove this for myself, but I have difficulties doing this.
My definition of the tautological bundle $\mathcal{U}$ comes from the universal exact sequence on the grassmanian $Gr(k,n+1)$, given as
$1 \rightarrow \mathcal{U} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}^{\oplus n+1} \rightarrow \mathcal{Q}\rightarrow 1$.
The closed immersion $j : Gr(k,n) \hookrightarrow Gr(k,n+1) $ which realises $Gr(k,n)$ as a closed subscheme of $Gr(k,n+1)$ has the property that $j^{*}\mathcal{U} \cong \mathcal{U}$ and $j^{*}\mathcal{Q} \cong \mathcal{Q}\oplus \mathcal{O}$.
My only decent thought to prove this zero locus property is that there is a map $\mathcal{U} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}^{\oplus n+1} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}$, where the second arrow is the projection onto the last direct summand. Perhaps this arrow maps into the kernel off $\mathcal{O}_{Gr(k,n+1)} \rightarrow j_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Gr(k,n)}$.
Even if this is true, I would have no idea how to show that the image is precisely the ideal sheaf corresponding to the closed subscheme $Gr(k,n) \subset Gr(k,n+1)$, and I don't know how I would show that this section is indeed regular, so that the Koszul complex is exact.
I'm pretty sure that the details must be written down somewhere, but I have not been able to find anything satisfactory.
Any help would be much appreciated!

You can get pretty far just thinking in terms of elementary linear algebra and eschewing scheme language. For example, the trivial bundle on $Gr(k, V) \cong Gr(k, n+1)$ in the middle of the sequence should really be thought of as $V \times Gr(k, V)$, i.e. with the ambient space $V$ as its fiber. The dual bundle has fiber $V^$, so a global section of $\mathcal{U}^$ can be given by picking a linear functional $s : V \to k$ and restricting it to each subspace $V’ \subset V$. We have $s|_{V’} \equiv 0$ iff $V’ \subseteq \ker s$, so the section vanishes on $Gr(k, \ker s) \cong Gr(k, n)$.

@JakeLevinson Ah, nice. I will try to translate what you said into scheme language, but this gives good intuition. Thank you.

@JakeLevinson But how would you go about showing this section is regular?

A semi-cheating answer is that it has to be regular by dimension counting: the vanishing locus has codimension $k$, which is also the rank of the bundle.

A medium answer is that if you unwind the description above in an affine chart, I think you get the vanishing of some coordinate functions (i.e. linear equations).

A final answer is that the “elementary” description above essentially translates directly into a description of the functor of points of the vanishing locus of the section $s$ (a map $X \to Z(s)$ is by definition a map $X \to Gr(k, V)$, i.e. some vector bundle data on $X$, such that…). You will see that this description is equivalent to the functor of points of $Gr(k, \ker s)$. It’s exactly what you were aiming for in your post - in terms of taking a subbundle of the trivial bundle with fiber $V$.

A summary of the conversation we had in the comments:
Let $V$ be a vector space and let $s : V \to \Bbbk$ be a nonzero linear function, with kernel $W$. This determines a global section of the dual tautological bundle $\mathcal{U}^*$ on $Gr(k, V)$, namely, on each $V’ \subset V$ we have the functional $s|_{V’}$.
Let $Z(s) \subseteq Gr(k, V)$ be the scheme-theoretic vanishing locus of the section. By examining some diagrams, $Z(s)$ has the property that $\mathcal{U}|_{Z(s)} \subseteq W \times Gr(k, V)$, the trivial subbundle with fiber $W$. Note that this is true scheme-theoretically. More generally, a subscheme $Y$ has this property iff $Y \subseteq Z(s)$ as subschemes, and similarly a map $f : Y \to Gr(k, V)$ factors through $Z(s)$ iff the pulled back bundles have the property $f^*\mathcal{U} \subseteq W \times Y$. In words, $Z(s)$ is the largest subscheme on which $\mathcal{U}$ is contained in the subbundle with fiber $W$.
On points this just says $s|_{V’} \equiv 0$ iff $V’ \subseteq W$. On schemes $Y$ it says $s|_Y$, or the pullback of $s$ to $Y$, is zero iff $Y \subseteq Z(s)$.
Unwinding this, we see that a map $f : Y \to Z(s)$ is equivalent to a rank-$k$ vector subbundle of the trivial bundle $W \times Y$, which is the functor of points of $Gr(k, W)$.
